# How do I make this if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, int

Apologies for the silly question, I am currently struggling to learn java. I need this code to work so that it will repeat unless '0' is entered for the studentNumber, I'm unsure of how to get the "please enter student number" part to work when I have to declare the int for that before the if statement? I'm not sure if I've approached this completely wrong or what, but I need to be able to repeat the data entry unless "0" is entered as the studentNumber. Thanks for any help!

```
class Main { 
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        int studentNumber = BIO.getInt();

        if(studentNumber > 0) {
            System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");

            System.out.print("#Please enter the coursework mark : ");
            int courseWork = BIO.getInt();

            System.out.print("#Please enter the exam mark : ");
            int examMark = BIO.getInt();

            double average = (double)(courseWork + examMark) / 2;

            System.out.printf("sn = " + studentNumber
                    + " ex = " + examMark + " cw = " + courseWork 
                    + " mark = " + average);
            } else {
                System.out.print("#End of data");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I be using a while statement or something instead?

Comment: switch the if with while

Comment: Move the prompt (`print("#Please enter the student number : ")`) to be before `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `while()` instead of `if`, along with the following changes:

```
System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");
int studentNumber = BIO.getInt();

while(studentNumber > 0) {
    System.out.print("#Please enter the coursework mark : ");
    int courseWork = BIO.getInt();

    System.out.print("#Please enter the exam mark : ");
    int examMark = BIO.getInt();

    double average = (double)(courseWork + examMark) / 2;
    System.out.printf("sn = " + studentNumber
            + " ex = " + examMark + " cw = " + courseWork 
            + " mark = " + average);

    System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");
    studentNumber = BIO.getInt();
} 

System.out.print("#End of data");
```

This, as opposed to the other answers, will ensure that even in the first iteration, you perform the check (and promt the user for the student number).

Comment: if I do this it says the variable is already defined (studentNumber)

Comment: @Austin I'm sorry, I updated it :) It should work now

Answer (score 3):

Use `while()`

```
while(studentNumber > 0){
  studentNumber = BIO.getInt();
   .........
   ........
}
```

### See also

- [while in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Scanner](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FScanner.html&ei=hdlYVLXrOYaPuAShxoDIAg&usg=AFQjCNGKCM1963whzInHG7dMQpVftNTOKg&sig2=4YY2-VJDtD-GH--uazc2ug&bvm=bv.78677474,d.c2E) to get the input from the user and process the input value

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConditionCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner BIO = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");
       int studentNumber = BIO.nextInt();

       if(studentNumber > 0) {
        System.out.print("#Please enter the coursework mark : ");
        int courseWork = BIO.nextInt();

        System.out.print("#Please enter the exam mark : ");
        int examMark = BIO.nextInt();

        double average = (double)(courseWork + examMark) / 2;
        System.out.printf("sn = " + studentNumber
                + " ex = " + examMark + " cw = " + courseWork 
                + " mark = " + average);
        } else {
            System.out.print("#End of data");
        }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `while` statement and do something as below:

```
class Main
    { 
        public static void main( String args[] )
        {
                int studentNumber = 1;
                While(studentNumber > 0)
                {
                studentNumber = BIO.getInt();

                System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");


                System.out.print("#Please enter the coursework mark : ");
                int courseWork = BIO.getInt();

                System.out.print("#Please enter the exam mark : ");
                int examMark = BIO.getInt();

                double average = (double)(courseWork + examMark) / 2;

                System.out.printf("sn = " + studentNumber + " ex = " + examMark + " cw = " + courseWork + " mark = " + average);
              }

                else
              {
                  System.out.print("#End of data");

              }
        }
    }
```